# why does Macos PowerChime use the network

Tags: macos, malware

PowerChime Sent Bytes:236 KB   Rcvd Bytes: 8 KB    Sent Packets: 7,210 Recvd Packets: 209
This alarms me!
Running Catalina 10.15.3 on a Macbook Pro 16"

Comment: PowerChime is a system app distributed by Apple. it's ostensible purpose is to sound a chime when you plug a portable into a power source, but it may have other functions. With such a small amount go data it may just be doing a handshake: testing if the machine is connected or some such before sounding the chime.  It's certainly not something you should be concerned about.

Comment: hmm, but sending near a quarter of a megabyte seems more than handshakes, or even full-body hugs. I'm not sure something's not f** with my machine.

Comment: Maybe it's more than a hug, but it's not like PowerChime got to third base... I guess my real point is that this is a deep system file. It would be hard to mess up even for someone with full administrator access to your machine, so if it's going sideways it's something Apple did wrong, and there's nothing to be done about it. And for all we know, this is intended behavior. Unless you're seeing an *actual* problem, I wouldn't waste time worrying about the behavior of opaque system files.

Comment: Could this be counting _local_ traffic to localhost or a UNIX socket?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking why apple does things is off topic. If you wanted to edit this to be “since this is communicating to the internet, how do I accomplish X?” I could see that being on topic. Can you edit in a practical problem you face that’s a bit more developed when “why did this happen?”

Comment: Just a datapoint for further discussion. My LuLu firewall shows that PowerChime was trying to connect to `fe80::aede:48ff:fe33:4455%en5`. PowerChime's purpose in life, as I understand it, is to make a sound when the laptop is plugged in; I don't understand why it needs to connect to the internet to do any of that.

Comment: Just tracked down an Air's full screen window that wouldn't go away telling me my battery was 30% Charged to a PowerChime process in a not responding state. Force quitting PowerChime and the damn window finally stops occluding my laptop screen. So if PowerChime was not responding because it was waiting on a network handshake that failed I'd sure like to know why I had to waste so much time as a result. Leaving this here on the off chance someone else stumbles into this.

Comment: Reeks of surveillance state corporate meddling but hey, what do I know… perhaps Apple uses WiFi to charge a laptop… seems totally uberzuber legit and totally not unconstitutional surveillance because Apple is a totally trustworthy corporate entity… right? … right? 

Edit: if the power chime does this, you can imagine what else does what. The only question I am left with is how humanity allowed this to happen. We had things figured out for a little while there and then jet fuel melted some steel beams and now we are here. But whatever total conspiracy theory, right fellas?

Comment: Aside from the aforementioned, the trace produced by sampling power chime reveals some interesting other details for a power chime… such as “RemoteViewServices”, “ProtectedCloudStorage”, “GeoServices”, “CorePhoneNumbers”, “SpeechRecognition”, and other frameworks… either I don’t understand why or how, or this is a whole lot more than a power chime… why initiate or even remotely touch any of the aforementioned if your sole purpose is to go “ding” when a cord is plugged into a port… so I guess my last comment stands justified ‍♂️ I hope someone figures this mystery out without getting 360-NSd